# Java non-static method cannot be refenced from a static context

Tags: java, static

I am new to java and having an issue calling a non static method

This is my main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Fish f1 = new Fish("Nemo");
    Fish f2 = new Fish("Dory");
    f2.setNumber(2);
    Fish m = new Fish("Bruce");
    m.setNumber(3);
    Fish.printAllFish();
}
```

This is my fish class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Fish {
protected String name;
protected int number;
protected List<Fish> fishList = new ArrayList<Fish>();


public Fish(String in){
name = in;
number = 1;
fishList.add(this);
}




public void printFish(){
    System.out.println("the fish called" + name + " is number " + number );
}
public void setNumber(int Number){
    this.number = number;
}
public int getNumber(){
 return number;   
}
public String getName(){
 return name;
}
public int getFishNumOf(){
    return fishList.size();

}

public void printAllFish(){
    int size = this.getFishNumOf();
    System.out.println("There are " + size + " fish:");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        String a = getName();
        int b = getNumber();
        System.out.println("The Fish " + a + " is number " + b );
    }
}
}
```

I  get the nonstatic error when trying to call printAllFish, I know I am probably making some rookie mistakes but I only just started to learn programming and things like classes, gets and sets still confuse me, any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `printAllFish`, `getFishNumOf` and `fishList` static and remove the `this` keyword before `getFishNumOf`. Then in the for loop you have to specify which fish you're getting the name and number of for each iteration of the loop. For instance:

```
for(Fish f : fishList)
    String a = f.getName();
    int b = f.getNumber();
    System.out.println("The Fish " + a + " is number " + b );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much MrAzzaman, you really helped me out! I will implement you for loop as it is much nicer :)

Comment: @Ser Davos - Also try to figure out/learn where and how to use static keyword, and every reason behind the solution provided

Answer (score 1):

`printAllFish` is `non-static` method and you are trying to call it in a static way i.e. using the class name and not the instance.

You should call it using one of the instance i.e. f1 or f2:

```
f1.printAllFish();
```

Comment: If I make printAllFish static, these lines are not static and throw up the same error; int size = this.getFishNumOf();,  String a = this.getName();, int b = getAge();. Thanks for the reply friend

Comment: @SerDavos static methods cannot access non-static fields. This is because static methods can be called without creating an instance. And if instance is not created then it does make sense to access intance fields.

Comment: All fixed now thanks Juned!

Comment: @SerDavos If you want to access non-static/instance fields in printAllFish then keep that method as non-static only. And simply call it using any of the instances.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call your initialized object method. not Fish.printAllFish() but f1.printAllFish(), f2.printAllFish() or m.printAllFish()

I suggest using a different class named FishContainer where it has a List object of Fish objects and when initializing a Fish object, you add it to FishContainer's list property and then call the printAllFish() from the container class.
Try sth like this:

```
FishContainer container = new FishContainer();
Fish f1 = new Fish("Nemo");
Fish f2 = new Fish("Dory");
f2.setNumber(2);
Fish m = new Fish("Bruce");
m.setNumber(3);

container.addFish(f1);
container.addFish(f2);
container.addFish(m);
container.printAllFish();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Apostolos, very useful :)